# How do I add data from an imported class

Tags: python, oop

I'm a taking a beginner programming class learning about Class. This is my first time posting. I'm trying to add cards from an imported class, but the result of the cards is a Non-type. I've created each card in the imported class but when the cards are appended to a deck, it outputs nonsense. Apologies if the format isn't pleasing, and thank you for your help.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self,suite,number):
        self.suite=suite
        self.number=number      
    
    def making_cards(suite,number):
        card=[]
        suite=["Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades"]       
        card_numbers=range(1,14,1)
        number.append("Ace")
        for x in suite:
            for y in card_numbers:
                card=[x, y]
                if isinstance(int(1), int):
                    card_numbers[0]="Ace"
                if isinstance(int(11), int):
                    card_numbers[10]="Jack"
                if isinstance(int(12), int):
                    card_numbers[11]="Queen"
                if isinstance(int(13), int):
                    card_numbers[12]="King"
                return card
        
    def get_display_string(self):
        print number,"of", suite
```

This is the main program that the class is being imported into, and can't edit or modify this part:

```
import random
from cards import Card

def create_deck():
    # The deck array-list will contain Cards
    deck = []

    # Build the deck, assuming the Card class was imported correctly
    for i in range(1, 4+1):
        for j in range(1, 13+1):
            deck.append(Card(i,j))

    return deck
def main():
    print ("The dealer opens a new pack of playing cards.")
    my_deck = create_deck()
    print my_deck
    print ("The dealer shuffles.")
    random.shuffle(my_deck)
    print ("The dealer pulls five cards from the top.")
    print ("And we see...")
    for c in my_deck[:5]:
        print ('\t' + c.get_display_string())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()
```

The nonsense output is as follows:
The dealer opens a new pack of playing cards.
[<cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2648>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2FC8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2488>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2188>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F20C8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2DC8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2408>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2148>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2AC8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2988>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051F2048>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EF508>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EF188>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EFD08>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EFC88>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EFF48>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EF808>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EF608>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EF448>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EFA88>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EFFC8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EF748>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EF388>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EFB48>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EF308>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EFDC8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x0000000005167CC8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051C2108>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051C2AC8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051C2E88>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051C2F88>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051C2708>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051C29C8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051C2B88>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051C2888>, <cards.Card instance at 0x0000000005021548>, <cards.Card instance at 0x0000000005021C88>, <cards.Card instance at 0x0000000005021E88>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EE108>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EE548>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EE8C8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EEC88>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EE908>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EE4C8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EEAC8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EE3C8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EEE08>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EE348>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EE0C8>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051EEA88>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051E2248>, <cards.Card instance at 0x00000000051E20C8>]
The dealer shuffles.
The dealer pulls five cards from the top.
And we see...

Comment: In `def __init__(self,suite,number):` you're not using the parameters to set anything

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  "nonesense" is not a specification.  Also, this fails to run due to at least one undefined symbol.

Comment: This is not an all-volunteer personal tutorial service.  This material is covered in thousands of paid courses, blogs, and examples online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a "warning", check out your first code block, the making_cards doesn't really have sense, I'm not sure why you put that for in for, the return will always be on the first iteration of the for loops and ill return [Ace, Clubs], etc. Try thinking a little more about that part.

Now as to what you're seeing in the console when running, I suppose you see something like <******.Tee object at 0x..............>. That's because when you're printing, you're printing a Card **object**, not a **string**, so Python does what it does and tells you details about that object. If you want to print let's say the suite and the number, you'd have to call out those attributes in the print like this:

```
print(card.suite)
print(card.number)
# or
print("{} {}".format(card.suite, card.number)
```

Also, one thing you're doing not okay is the constructor of the Card class. Check it out again, you're initializing self.suite and self.number with [] instead of the actual values, if you do the print as I stated above, Python would print on the console [] and you'd come back saying that it's also printing non-sense.

You're on the right track, but think again what you wrote in the code as it doesn't really make sense (and for sure you're understanding it way less because of it and you're getting annoyed with it not working). If this is from a course, I'd recommend going back to the part where you're explained how the classes work, the return statements, and the loops. After that, think how the app should work and draw some flow diagram on paper, this might help you write the code.